# Sharepoint basics and any useful resources?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-api

Sorry about having 3 questions in one but they are closely related and should be simple for someone familiar.

I'm used to coding Java/Obj C/PHP and am finding trying to modify a template somewhat annoying partly because it doesn't make sense but mostly I can't find resources.

I am editing a master template and have gotten the basics but some things still allude me.

With the ContentPlaceHolders, is there a way to use it more than once? Someone posted some code about how you can do this but it said I couldn't use code here.

Is there a way to modify these ContentPlaceHolders without using Sharepoint designer?

I thought using the SharePoint: tag would be a possible way around this, but I can't find any docos on the possible tags and what they do and where to use them.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This one is a great starting point http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/38749/why-does-everybody-hate-sharepoint :)

Answer (score 1):

A ContentPlaceHolder in a master page only maps to one Content section in a page/page layout.

Yes, you can modify the contents of ContentPlaceHolder using code, building a control tree.

The SharePoint tag prefix is used to signify a different control namespace, but there is no sharepoint:placeholder

Maybe if you explain what you are trying to do, we might be able to advise you the best way.

Comment: Bit more detail on the ContentPlaceHolder modification process? like how do I get to those sections of code? With the SharePoint Tag is there an API or something that explains what all of the different tags do?